# Portugol duvidas sobre atribuição de valores a caracteres

Tags: portugol

Gostaria de saber como atribuir a caracteres valores já digitados pelo usuário no laço de repetição.

Código:

```
nu,cont,contp :inteiro

pot :inteiro

tipo :caractere
inicio


cont <- 1
escreval("digite a qtd de usinas")
leia (nu)

escreval ("H-hidroeletrica")
escreval("T-Termoeletrica")
escreval("E-EOLICA")

repita

escreval("digite o TIPO de cada usina ")
leia(tipo)    

cont <- cont+1

ate (cont > nu)    

repita

contp <- contp+1

escreval("Digite a **POTENCIA** de cada usina ")
leia(pot)    

ate  contp = nu)
```

Minha dúvida e eu pedi para o usuário dizer qual o tipo da usina H-E-O. Logo abaixo pedir para dizer a potência gostaria de saber como atribuir os tipos aos valores digitados?

Para um melhor entendimento onde quero chegar o exercício é esse:

Após ler esta quantidade de usinas, o programa solicita para cada usina qual o tipo de usina ( H-hidroeletrica, T-termoeletrica, E-eolica) e qual a potência gerada, após lidos os dados de todas as usina o programa contabiliza o total de energia gerado para cada tipo e avalia em qual bandeira a região deve operar. quando mais que 20% de energia gerada for proveniente de termoelétrica opera-se em bandeira vermelha. Quando a geração de termelétrica estiver entre 10 e 20% a região opera em bandeira amarela?

Comment: Parceiro tu escreveu de um jeito tão estranho que no fim eu não entendi a tua dúvida...

Comment: vou resumir ...   eu preciso fazer com que o programa atribua os valores aos caracteres digitados pelo usuario. para apartir dai eu calcular a porcentagem de cada tipo de usina ...

Comment: solicite ao usuario a quantidade de usinas de energia em uma região, apos ler esta quantidade de usinas, o programa solicita para cada usina qual o tipo de usina ( h-hidroeletrica T- termoeletrica E- eolica e qual a potencia gerada, apos lifdos os daods de todas as usina o programa contabiliza o total de energia gerado para cada tipo e avalia em qual bandeira a região deve operar. quando mais que 20% de nergeia gerada forproveniente de termoeletrica opera-se em bandeira vermelha. quando a geração de termeletrica estver entre 10 e 20 % a região opera em bandeira amarela

Comment: Você quer fazer tipo um menu?

Answer (score 1):

Não dá para entender direito o que você quer, mas acho que isso te ajuda:

```
INICIO

    VARIAVEIS
    quantidade, potencia: inteiro;
    tipo: char;

    ESCREVA("Digite a quantidade de usinas: ");
    LEIA(quantidade);

    ESCREVA("Digite o tipo de usina: ");
    LEIA(tipo);

    ESCREVA("Digite a potência gerada: ");
    LEIA(potencia);

    SE (potencia >= 20) ENTAO
        ESCREVA("Bandeira Vermelha");

    SE (potencia > 10 E potencia < 20) ENTAO
        ESCREVA("Bandeira Amarela");

FIM
```